how to ignore slides per group on scrolling (by dragging) in swiper js
I have this javascript code
const swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  direction: "horizontal",
  loop: true,
  velocity: 200,
  spaceBetween: 30,
  slidesPerView: 6,
  slidesPerGroup: 6,
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
});

The slider will have 6 slides in the view and each pagination bullet will correspond to 6 slides due to slidesPerGroup set to 6
However this is affecting my scrolling (by dragging) behavior. Whenever I scroll, 6 slides are getting scrolled at the same time, like there are being taken like one slide.
Is there I way I can make the swiper to ignore slidesPerGroup on scrolling and only use it on pagination bullets
or is there another way I can make swiper to scroll as usual while ensuring that each pagination bullet will correspond to 6 slides
I tried using freemode, However freemode doesn't allow slides snapping
